# Is there any MathML and LaTex editor for CKEDITOR

Tags: latex, ckeditor, mathml

Is there any best plugin to integrate with CKEDITOR for editing and inserting a **MathML** and **LaTex** equations.

I have seen some of the plugins in CKEDITOR plugin site but those are not up to the mark and not easy to insert and edit complex equations. It would be helpful if is there any other plugins available for CKEDITOR.

Comment: Try [MathEx][1] plugin for CKEditor

it supports MathML and latex 

Note : please use helpers to convert string to plugin readable format.

please refer README for further details


  [1]: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/MathEx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely WIRIS editor matches your requirements. There is a JavaScript MathML and LaTeX editor integrated with ckeditor. The user interface is quite easy to use and you will be able to quickly input math formulas and equations. See [www.wiris.com/editor/demo](http://www.wiris.com/editor/demo). In addition, they have a great support team.

Comment: Hi @Dani, i checked out this WIRIS editor demo, i downloaded the plugin from wiris site and tried to integrate with CKEditor, but i am unable to do it... in the documentation "2.2 For ASP.NET servers, Create an application through your IIS control panel with root directory at to ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration." i created an IIS application(virtual directory) to this folder, but there is already an asp.net solution in that integration folder. i am unable to find a way to integrate it, Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Ramesh, could you be more specific with what errors do you obtain? For example, you can check the following:  1. Visit http://<your-domain>/<your-folder>/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/test.aspx.  2. Open a page with ckeditor and you will see the icon to insert formulas.